# Codigo 400 al generar preferencia

Tags: json, mercadopago

Estoy teniendo un problema, que al generar una preferencia de pago con este JSON:

```
{
   "items":[
      {

         "title":"pago 3 anticipo",
         "category_id":null,
         "quantity":1,
         "currency_id":"ARS",
         "unit_price":1250.0
      }
   ],
   "back_urls":{

      "success":"http://localhost:54815/paymentSuccess",
      "pending":"http://localhost:54815/paymentPending",
      "failure":"http://localhost:54815/paymentFailure"
   }
}
```

Algunas veces retorna un 201 (OK), pero otras veces me retorna 400 con el código `invalid_items`.

Mi código es el siguiente (C#):

```
MP mp = new MP(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
mp.sandboxMode(true);

string sJson = getBodyJason();

Hashtable Hashpreference = mp.createPreference(sJson);
```

Comment: Con el mismo JSON te retorna el diferentes resultados? el error 400 (bad request/solicitud incorrecta) te indica normalmente que lo que estás mandando tiene un problema

Comment: es como si tuviera que esperar un tiempo o algo, la verdad nose, porque el json es el mismo lo único que cambia es el titulo o monto (siempre con el mismo formato numerico)

Comment: intenta hacer la misma llamada utilizando SOAPUI o PostMan, y checa si en el body/content del response te manda algún detalle más de qué es lo que esta mal

Comment: en el campo ["cause"] es un array, pero esta vacio